# d3js continuous node color network - not able to figure out the problem

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong in the following html code. I have a JSON file with a "cohesive" attribute which is a continuous variable. I want to draw a force directed graph on D3JS using the JSON file with the node color reflecting the difference in cohesive energy. When I run this script, I don't get any errors but there is no output as well. I just started with HTML scripting so please forgive me if I am making a very silly error but I would really appreciate if someone could point out what I am doing wrong.

```js
function convertRange(value, r1, r2) {
  return (value - r1[0]) * (r2[1] - r2[0]) / (r1[1] - r1[0]) + r2[0];
}
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height");

var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear(d3.interpolateViridis);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
    return d.id;
  }))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

d3.json("Perovskite_info.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
      return Math.sqrt(d.value);
    });

  var node = svg.append("g")
    .attr("nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return colorScale(convertRange(d.cohesive_en, [1.6, 7.2], [0, 1]));
    })
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended));

  node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });

  simulation
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
      .attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    node
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });
  }
});

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

```css
.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

<h1>Cohesive Energy Calculation</h1>

<svg width="1060" height="800"></svg>
```

This is how one my json begins:

```
{"directed": false, "multigraph": false, "graph": {}, "nodes": [{"pos": [-37.50340668168362, -0.6442713601030169], "cohesive_en": 5.752120797750001, "cohesive": 5.752120797750001, "cluster": 1, "similarity": 0.6371195466189876, "id": "PrCoO3"},
```

For the full JSON please follow this link: https://api.myjson.com/bins/m3gd8

Edit: So I figured out what the problems were:

First off, as one of the answers stated, I was using d3.v5 but using the d3v4 api to import data. Secondly, I also needed to import the d3 interpolate module which I hadn't done. So the code wasn't working. This question was asked at a point where I had done d3 for 2 days so the quality of the code is low.

Comment: Can you provide the full path to `Perovskite_info.json` in the snippet to be able to reproduce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use a D3v4 API of loading a file.

D3v5 use the Fetch API

```
// d3.json("Perovskite_info.json", function(error, graph) {
d3.json("Perovskite_info.json").then( function(graph) {
    //if (error) throw error;
```

Then there is a problem in how you add the nodes compared to the links but you will find that.

Why do the colorScale Math yourself in `convertRange`?

There is no color yet but that is a different problem.